# Multiple problems with HTC M8S after rom upgrade

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, custom-roms, bootloader, htc

I have an old HTC M8S I'm trying to give a new lease on life by getting off the stock ROM. It's an EE (read Orange UK) branded phone.

- romver: 1.11.61.2
- CID: ORANG001
- ModelID: 0PKV10000
- Project: M8_QU_UL_L50_SENSE60

After switching on debug mode and unlocking the boot loader I installed TWRP specific to that model (twrp-recovery-2.8.6.0-m8s-qlul.img) and it worked, recovery worked fine. After that I wiped and attempted to install the Lineage M8S ROM, which did not work.

Now I have a phone that won't boot and can't be accessed on USB, the device shows up in adb as offline. The phone has an SD card, and I've loaded the stock recovery back on, which was successful. I then attempted loading the original ROM onto the SD card as 0PKVIMG.zip, however I got a message about 0PKVDIAG.zip not being present. The device still shows up as

I am not sure how to proceed to get this phone back, several hours of research has been very contradictory. I'd like to get a better rom on than the stock because it was full of trash apps and they stopped making releases for it, but I'm happy to get back to stock and try again if that's what it takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the ROMs [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/htc-one-m8/one-m8s-general) from XDA Forums, as they can help you to fix your problem. 
 You can also try a higher version of TWRP, such as v3.2.1.

Comment: Thanks @KirandeepMaan, I've been all over that site for some time without progress, hence the question here.

Comment: @GdD try higher twrp version like 3.2.1 or higher may help you if not available try to port yourself.

Comment: I followed your suggestion to use a newer version of TWRP and it works now, much appreciated!

Comment: Most welcome @GdD